# Saving number like 00402 in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to save a strings like 00300 and 000029620 as a number in mongodb.

This is the result

```
db.test.save({"number": 00402})
{ "_id" : ObjectId(""), "number" : 258 }

db.test.save({"number": 00300})
{ "_id" : ObjectId(""), "number" : 192 }
```

Comment: I'd like mongo to drop the zeros in front.

Comment: It looks like they're being interpreted as octal representation.

Comment: `00402` is an octal integer literal that is `258` in decimal. Your `'00402'` is not a number, it is a string that just happens to contain only digit characters.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hand MongoDB `00402` and have it store it as `402` then you could send the `00402` in as a string and use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) with a radix of 10 to turn it into an integer:

```
db.test.save({"number": parseInt('00402', 10)})
```

That will give you `{ "number" : 402 }` in your `test` collection.

I think you'd be better off handling this sort of thing in your client code though, build the appropriate integer outside MongoDB and then send the integer into MongoDB.

Comment: is it possible to use this with mongoimport?

Comment: @Bingimar: I suspect that those aren't numbers at all, they're just strings that happen to contain only digit characters; if they're zip codes or similar things then they're not numbers. AFAIK you'll have to import them into a temporary collection that uses a string for `number` and then fix up the data once it is inside MongoDB. I still don't think they're numbers, if you're not doing arithmetic on them then they're really strings.

Comment: Yeah I understand, its just how the data is supplied to me from this vendor. Its a huge flat file and they zero fill empty space. I wrote an import script that finished in 20 hours and imported the whole data. 230 million rows. In the script I made sure to delete space and zeros.

Comment: Mongodb crashes after a while when I add an index to that collection. What could be the caus?

Comment: I think its related to maxfiles in launchctl.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I ran into that on my macbook--in Lion you can do this to increase the limit: `limit maxfiles 2048 unlimited`

Answer (score 0):

Another option: you can use the NumberLong constructor, which will interpret strings as base 10:

```
> db.test.save({"number":NumberLong("00402")});
> db.test.save({"number":NumberLong("00300")});  
> db.test.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f52b230621918e231bc55d5"), "number" : NumberLong(402) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f52b233621918e231bc55d6"), "number" : NumberLong(300) }
```